# prove Diophantine equation has no solution $\prod_{i=1}^{2014}(x+i)=\prod_{i=1}^{4028}(y+i)$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, contest-math

> show that this equation
>   $$(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)\cdots(x+2014)=(y+1)(y+2)(y+3)\cdots(y+4028)$$
>   have no positive integer solution.

This problem is china TST (2014),I remember a famous result? maybe is a Erdos have proof this problem?

maybe this follow have some paper?
$$(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)\cdots(x+k)=(y+1)(y+2)(y+3)\cdots(y+2k)$$
positive integer solution?

Thank you for help

Comment: I suspect that by the time $x$ is large enough for both lhs and rhs to have the same power of $2$, $x$ is so large that $\prod x+i$ will have a prime factor that $\prod y+i$ doesn't.

Comment: Looking at $v_p$ of both sides we get that some term on the LHS has to be divisible by $p^{\left\lfloor\frac k{2p}\right\rfloor}$.

Comment: There is an interesting paper from 1994 on arithmetic progressions with equal products here: http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa68/aa6817.pdf. The authors mention an earlier paper by two of them (Saradha and Shorey) where it is proven that the only integer solution to $(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)\cdots(x+k)=(y+1)(y+2)(y+3)\cdots(y+2k)$ is $8\cdot9\cdot10=1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot5\cdot6$. The general results look quite difficult, suggesting that there’s an ad-hoc approach to solving the contest problem.

Comment: What is china TST (2014)? A math-contest?

Comment: @user37238 TST = Team Selection Test, typically towards the IMO. In China there could be several rounds of TSTs.

Comment: Is there a link to TST 2014?  (use tag [tag:contest-math] for competition problems )

Comment: Since this is TST, this means that high school students (in theory) would be able to solve it. Really darn smart high school students, sure, but there should be some "elegant" solution lurking around here.

Comment: Here are some proposed solutions: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h582007p3439358

Answer (score 6):

The $\nu_2$ (the exponent of the greatest power of $2$ dividing) of the RHS is at least $4010$, so there must be an element $\xi\in X=\{x+1,\ldots,x+2014\}$ such that $\nu_2(\xi)\geq 1996$. This gives that, if a solution $(x,y)$ exists, it must be huge, with $x>2^{1995}$ and $y$ around $\sqrt{x}$. For the same reason (with $\nu_3$ in place of $\nu_2$), if a solution exists, a multiple of $3^{995}$ must lie in $X$. So many multiples of huge powers of different primes must lie in a relatively short interval: this is quite uncommon, since it gives that
$$ \Omega\left(\prod X\right) $$
is extremely big.

We also have that all the primes in the $[2015,4028]$ interval divide $\prod X$:
$$2017,2027,2029,2039,\ldots,4027\; | \prod X\tag{2},$$
so, additionally, $x$ can lie in a few residue classes $\pmod{\prod_{2014<p<4028}p}$.

Comment: Surely we can achieve $|a.2^{1995}-b.3^{995}|=1$ by Bezout?

Comment: @OscarCunningham: You're clearly right, edited.

Answer (score 1):

OK this doesn't quite work, but here's some ideas.

Let $k=2014$ for ease of notation. Suppose we have a solution.

(1) Expand the RHS as $\prod_{i=1}^{k} (y^2+(2k+1)y+i(2k+1-i))$. We see that $y^2+(2k+1)y+2k<x<y^2+(2k+1)y+k^2$.

(2) Suppose for a prime $p$ and $a\ge1$, $p^a$ is the largest power dividing any factor $y+i$ on the RHS. By (1), we have that each factor on the LHS is of the form
$$y^2+(2k+1)y+c=(y+i)^2+(2k+1-2i)(y+i) +i^2-(2k+1)i+c$$ for $c\in(2k,k^2+2k)$. Letting $y'=y+i$, this is 
$$y'^2+(2k+1-2i)y'+d$$ for $d\in (-k^2,k^2)$. Now assuming $2k<k^2<p^a$, we have $d<p^a$ so the only way this is divisible by $p^a$ is if $d=0$; then the highest power of $p$ that can divide this is $p^{a+\log_{p}(2k)}$. Suppose the highest power of $p$ dividing a term on the LHS is $p^{a+j}$; we have $j\le \log_p (2k)$.

(3) Assuming $k^2<p^a$ we have
$$
v_p(LHS)=\sum_{i=1}^{a+j}\left\lfloor{\frac{x+k}{p^i}}\right\rfloor
-\left\lfloor{\frac{x}{p^i}}\right\rfloor
$$
$$
v_p(RHS)=\sum_{i=1}^{a}\left\lfloor{\frac{y+2k}{p^i}}\right\rfloor
-\left\lfloor{\frac{y}{p^i}}\right\rfloor
$$
Using $x\ge \lfloor x\rfloor>x-1$ and noting that the terms in the sum for $\log_p(2k)<i\le a$ are all 1 in the 2nd sum and at most 1 in the first sum,
$$
0=v_p(RHS)-v_p(LHS)\ge \left[\sum_{i=1}^{\log_p (2k)}\left(\frac{2k}{p^i}-1\right)
-\left(\frac{k}{p^i}+1\right)\right]-\log_p(2k)\ge \frac kp-3\log_p(2k).
$$

Answer (score 1):

According to Theorem 4 in the paper "[On the ratio of two blocks of consecutive integers](http://repository.ias.ac.in/67750/1/67750.pdf)," the equation
$$(x+1)\cdots(x+k)=(y+1)\cdots(y+2k)$$
has only one solution in integers $x\geq0,y\geq0,k\geq2$ and it is given by $x=7,y=0,k=3$.

Comment: +1 for the good reference. But surely this, with its many many lemmas and huge buildup is not what was intended on the TST. I think there must be something special about $2014$. Perhaps its prime factorization or a prime that is near $2014$?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but it's too long for a comment. Perhaps it helps:

Observe that $$\frac{(y+1)\cdots(y+4028)}{4028!}={y+4028\choose y},$$ which is an integer. Then $$(x+1)\cdots(x+2014)=4028!{y+4028\choose y},$$ so the left hand side is an integer multiple of $4028!$.

This yields a large lower bound for $x$ as follows. The product $(x+1)\cdots(x+2014)$ must be divisible by the product of $p$, $2p$, and $3p$, for any prime with $3p\le4028$. If $p>1007$, there isn’t room for three multiples of $p$ between $x+1$ and $x+2014$, so one of the $x+j$ must be a multiple of $p^2$. Using $p=1327$, then $x>1327^2$.

You can also get some partial congruences for $x$. The prime $4027$ divides $(x+1)\cdots(x+2014)$, so $(x \mbox{ mod } 4027)\ge2013$.

[Note that in my comment to the original question, I provide a reference to a general result implying that there is no solution to the original equation.]